# use of uncountable nouns

Tags: word-usage, usage

"One of the traditional music of Japan is hogaku."
Is this sentence grammatically correct?
It was generated by Bing, which claimed that "one of" can be followed by an uncountable noun when the noun is referred to as a genre or field.

Answer (score 3):

> One of the traditional music of Japan is hogaku.

*Music* is noncount and cannot be used in a construction like that shown above.

A search for [one of the music *](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+of+the+music+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows us that the *music*
in all the listed uses is an attributive noun.

To use music as a noun after *one of the*, we need to insert partitive nouns like [*types* or *genres*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=genres+of+traditional+music%2Ctypes+of+traditional+music&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3):

> One of the types (or genres) of traditional music of Japan is hogaku.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. 
Actually, I shared the same idea, so I was doubtful about what Bing said.
Hmm … it looks like he should not be considered so much of an authority regarding English:(

Comment: ＠Mary 
And thank you, the editor Mary-san!
I really appreciate your kindness✌